# Can someone explain, step by step, what this function is doing

Tags: python, recursion

```
def hanoi(n,f,v,t):
    if n == 0:
        pass
    else:
        hanoi(n-1,f,t,v)
        print(f"Move disc from {f} to {t}.")
        hanoi(n-1,v,f,t)

hanoi(3,"a","b","c")
```

I'm studying recursion and I can't figure out this "Tower of Hanoi" function. It works fine, but I don't understand exactly what it's doing. For example one of the instructions the function prints is:
"Move disc from c to b."
But it seems to me that {f} can only ever be "a" or "b"?
It seems easy to understand when (n = 2), because it calls (n = 1) which prints "Move disc from a to b."
Then moves back to (n = 2) which prints "Move disc from a to c."
Then it calls (n = 1) which prints "Move disc from b to c."
But I don't understand what's happening with larger values for n.

Comment: Li es in the function: 1. unnecessary, 2. unnecessary, 3. should be `if n:` or safer `if n <= 0:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Imo, a the best way to wrap you head around any recursive function is to write down (like on paper, old-school style) what is happening in some form.

Why use paper? It's easier and faster to draw random stuff than on a computer. This one is fairly simple, but with more complicated recursion it may be impractical to write everything out explicitly. In those cases, I like to summarize stuff symbolically, draw diagrams etc.

Second best is to make it print stuff in a small example. To do that, let's modify your initial code a bit.

```
def hanoi(n,_from,,t):
    print(f"Hanoi called: n:{n}, f:{f}, v:{v}, t:{t}")
    if n == 0:
        pass
    else:
        hanoi(n-1,f,t,v)
        print(f"Move disc from {f} to {t}. n:{n}")
        hanoi(n-1,v,f,t)

hanoi(3,"a","b","c")
```

The output yields:

```
Hanoi called: n:3, f:a, v:b, t:c (4)
Hanoi called: n:2, f:a, v:c, t:b (2)
Hanoi called: n:1, f:a, v:b, t:c (1)
Move disc from a to c. n:1       (1)
Move disc from a to b. n:2       (2)
Hanoi called: n:1, f:c, v:a, t:b (3)
Move disc from c to b. n:1       (3)
Move disc from a to c. n:3       (4)
Hanoi called: n:2, f:b, v:a, t:c (6)
Hanoi called: n:1, f:b, v:c, t:a (5)
Move disc from b to a. n:1       (5)
Move disc from b to c. n:2       (6)
Hanoi called: n:1, f:a, v:b, t:c (7)
Move disc from a to c. n:1       (7)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If you then compare this to this [image]

Notice how your first call, not satisfying the base condition (n==0) continues to "drill down" into the recursion. Once the base case is reached, then the recursion unstacks the calls - you move out from the LAST recursive call (n==1, the first move disk). Then n==2 (the 2nd move disk) etc....

Perhaps not so ironically, the tower of Hanoi itself is a pretty good analogy for how recursion works: you essentially stack calls (e.g. what you're eventually going to do) into a big pile. Then once you're done stacking new calls (e.g. you've reached your base case, n==0 here) then you pick up whatever call was last put onto you callstack & execute that.

EDIT: I've removed the n==0 calls to Hanoi (since they don't do anything and just confuse stuff). I've added in parenthese the step in the image that corresponds to each call on the image (2), (3), etc.... Each # will be present twice - once when we execute it (e.g. "move disk from...") and once when we put onto our callstack ("Hanoi called....").

As you can see, when we have a call to Hanoi with a n>1 number, a few of those calls will be stacked (say (1) (2) (4) ). When we get to n==0, we'll unstack those gradually. So we do a --> c first, which is (1), because that call was stacked onto the recursion stack last. E.g. (4) with n==3 was added first, but before we could execute it the recursion forced us to stack another with n==2 (2), and n==1 (1). Only at that point could we start to execute our backlog of calls to Hanoi. We'll get as to why the very first call to Hanoi is labelled (4) and not (3) just below. Just make sure you get this first part right.

Then we do a ---> b (which is (2) ) right after. But at that point n==2, so when we do that call to Hanoi, before we proceed with (4), we add another call on the stack (3). Since that one was added last, we unstack (3) right away. Then the only call we have left to pop from the callstack is (4). Since its n==3, that will bring us to add to more new calls on the recursion stack, (6) and (5). Again, we unstack them in the opposite order (since (5) is "on top" of (6) ). With (6), n==2, so we'll add another call to Hanoi, which will be (7). At that point, we don't add anymore calls to the stack, so we get out of the recursion completely.

Comment: In your output, the third statement is: Hanoi called: n:1, f:a, v:b, t:c. But the function call is the same as its parent: hanoi(n-1,f,t,v). So I would think the output would be: Hanoi called: n:1, f:a, v:c, t:b. Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: Added details  & corresponding numbers. Should be clearer. Just take it step by step, one line after the other

Answer (score 2):

It helps to formulate the problem in pseudocode first:

```
move_tower(height_of_tower, "origin", "destination", "helper"):
    if height_of_tower is 1:
        move disk directly from "origin" to "destination"
    else:
        move height_of_tower-1 disks from "origin" to "helper" using "destination"
        move remaining single disk from "origin" to "destination"
        move height_of_tower-1 disks from "helper" to "destination" using "origin"
```

This pseudocode can be immediately translated to Python code. Your base case with `n = 0` is just another way to write this, because for n=1 both function calls in the `else` block won't do anything (the base case n=0 is just `pass`).

A recursive function has two important properties: 
1. First, it defines a base case with a trivial solution, which is given directly.
2. Otherwise, it explains how the solution can be obtained from partial solutions; for this, any function can be used, including the recursive function itself. The only important thing is that it's called with reduced input data, so that at some point the base is hit.

Concerning your questions: "But it seems to me that {f} can only ever be "a" or "b"? ... But I don't understand what's happening with larger values for n."

No, {f} becomes the "origin", "destination" and "helper" rod dependent on the situation. It can help to write the function calls down for a small n, e.g. n = 3, and draw the recursion tree (a popular example is the [recursive Fibonacci function](https://medium.com/launch-school/recursive-fibonnaci-method-explained-d82215c5498e)). E.g., if n = 3, this is what happens:

1. move_tower(2, "origin", "helper", "destination") is called = transfer 2 disks from "origin" to "helper" (and you already know how this works, right?)
2. move the remaining disk directly from "origin" to "destination"
3. move_tower(2, "helper", "destination", "origin") = transfer 2 disks from "helper" (where we put them in step 1) to "destination" using "origin" as helper

In general, it's hard to really "think recursively". It helps to think about your function as a regular function, which can use any other function to achieve the desired result, including itself, but with a reduced data set. The base case makes sure that it doesn't run forever.

Answer (score 1):

Line 1: hanoi takes input n, f, v, t

2:      if n is 0 dont do anything

3:      otherwise,

4:      run hanoi with n set as n-1

5:      print some stuff using f

6:      run hanoi with inputs switched around

7:

8: Run hanoi with those steps

This is just explaining the code here to help you, not tell you what it does exactly.

This is relate to the Tower of Hanoi function as you mentioned and [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/blog/developers/tower-hanoi-recursion-game-algorithm-explained/) is a more in depth detail. It is recursive because it runs the function within itself.

Answer (score 1):

For your example of 3 disks `hanoi(3,"a","b","c")`, the best explanation IMHO is in the picture on [this blog](http://viswanathancse.blogspot.com/2018/10/exercise-no1-implement-and-solve-tower.html):

[image]

It explains all the steps (from 0 to 7) by picture.

For the case of an unknown n value, a possible situation when to use this function is when you have:

- n ordered objects in to move from an origin X to a destination Y with the order kept intact.
- only one object to move at a time with just 3 rods.